# VS2010 Not Always Building Before Debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have had a problem where VS2010 will not build my projects before debugging.  Even when they have never been built before (i.e. on a fresh checkout from source control).

I will either find I am stepping through on the wrong lines of code (because the symbols are out of date), or an error message if there is no build output (bin\debug folder is empty).

Performing a build manually before debugging is the workaround.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 isn't building before a run when there are code changes. It was doing working yesterday.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646858/visual-studio-2010-isnt-building-before-a-run-when-there-are-code-changes-it-wa)

Comment: @Hans I did wonder, but it's one of those things that's hard to formulate a search for if you've not seen the previous question. :)

Comment: Is there a configuration option for getting it to build with a custom build tool, say, [IncrediBuild](http://www.xoreax.com/)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm answering this myself, so that Stack Overflow can be the canonical answer to this problem in case someone else experiences the same thing.

Essentially it's a VS configuration issue.  Navigate to the options as follows:

> Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->On Run, when projects are out of date:

and make sure it is set to "Always Build" if it is not already.

Hope this helps someone, it's caused me a lot of trouble for weeks now.

Comment: I always find it funny when I struggle with something for days and then seconds after submitting the question to SO I find the answer.

Comment: @tster Actually I posted the question and immediately answered it, because I'd already found the answer and thought it might be helpful.  More helpful than the chaps on Connect, anyway. :)

Comment: Good anwser. Also ... the "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" may need to be unticked too, if you are changing a project that will be loaded by the startup project at run time, not directly referenced.

Comment: Great! This was helpful for me in a different way: I don't want VS to build every time since I like to build from the command line sometimes.  So I set "On Run" to prompt me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the configuration manager, and change Debug->Mixed CPU to Debug->Any CPU, I had resolved mine with the same option.

Answer (score 1):

What resolved the problem for me was going to the configuration manager and making sure the "Build" checkbox was checked.  In my case, it had somehow become un-checked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've found your answer and checked a
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run
And a value of "On Run, when projects are out of date" is "Prompt to Build", but VS does not prompt!
But then I found a problem in "Configuration Manager" - for some reason a mark "Build" disappear. It happened to my projects when I create a some project based on some another one using a copying a files and changing a project's and solution's GUIDs, names etc. inside a proj/sln files manually.