# VSCode CMake Extension rebuild all project each time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, cmake, build

I'm working on a project in C++ configured using CMake.
Each time I build the project, all files are recompiled, which is unbearable considering the time it takes.

#### With Visual Studio Code

I'm trying to use VSCode and the CMake Extension.
The `CMake:Configure` command works well and so does the `CMake:Build` command. It takes a lot of time to compile because I use highly templatized header-only libraries like Eigen3, Boost and CGAL, so I need to build a pre-compiled header. It build some librairies too. But it is normal that it takes time for a first compilation.

However, if I build the target again (without modifying anything in the code) the compilation is completely redone ! I just want the modified source files or librairies to be re-compiled. Or if a header in the list of pre-compiled headers is modified, only then should the pre-compiled headers be recompiled.

#### With Visual Studio 2019

I thought that VSCode didn't work with a concept of "project", and therefore had to reconfigure and recompile the whole project every time it was launched.
So I decided to generate a Visual Studio Solution with the CMake-GUI program and use Visual Studio 2019 instead of VSCode.
Now when I build a second time my project, nothing is recompiled and the program is directly lauched. Visual Studio say :

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Wonderful!
Unfortunately not..., because if I modify a file, Visual Studio keeps telling me that everything is up-to-date and my modifications are not taken into account. I need to "Rebuild" the project so that everything will be recompiled, which does not solve my problem as it takes a lot of time.

#### Question

How to recompile only modified source files, librairies or pre-compiled headers (with VS Code, Visual Studio or both) ?

---

**Plaform** : Windows 10

## Edit 15.04.21

I did some more methodical testing today to find out what the problem might be.
I used a very simple project to do the tests.

#### CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("HelloCMake")
add_executable (HelloCMake "HelloCMake.cpp")
```

#### HelloCMake.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello CMake !" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### 1. With VSCode and CMake Tools Extension

> With the [CMake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) Extension, VSCode can configure and build a CMake project. It generate a Visual Studio Solution (`.sln`).

1. Build the target with CMake Tools Extension which makes VSCode to run the command :

   ```sh
   cmake --build <PROJECT_DIR>/build --config Release --target HelloCMake -- 
   /maxcpucount:14
   ```
2. The entire target is compiled
3. I build it again (without changes)
4. The target is completely recompiled again

The problem is that the target is completely recompiled, every time. I asked the question directly to the CMake Tools developers. [*GitHub Issue*](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1768)

### 2. .sln project generated by CMake (Visual Studio 2019)

1. I generated a Visual Studio Solution with CMake and open it.
2. I build my project HelloCMake
3. I do some modifications in source file
4. I build the project again, but Visual Studio never takes my modifications into account. The builds are always "up-to-date".

The problem is that Visual Studio does not take my changes into account. I have to rebuild the project, which takes too much time.

### 3. Directly open CMake project with Visual Studio 2019 (Ninja)

> If you open a CMakeList.txt with Visual Studio 2019, it is not a Visual Studio Solution that is generated but a Ninja one.

It seems that this way the compilation works correctly !

According to this research, it is the CMake Tools Extension for VSCode as well as the Visual Studio Solution that cause problems.

**I can't figure out why such a simple project doesn't compile properly with a Visual Studio Solution generated by CMake.**

Comment: Does this happen with the ninja build system and what would a simple CMake file that reprroduce the error look like?

Comment: I wonder If you want to recompile only modified code with VS? If so, I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402882/how-to-configure-vs-to-compile-only-changed-code

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I have post an edit in the OP, with a simple code to reproduce and a test with Ninja. I haven't managed to generate a Ninja build directly with CMake yet, but Visual Studio 2019 uses Ninja when you want to open a CMake project without generating a `.sln` file, and it seems to work. But it's strange that compilation is a problem when using a Visual Studio Solution.

Comment: @CharrièreMaxime The vscode cmake-tools extension should be able to use Ninja based solutions and generate them. Passing `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja` in the CMake configure options should usually be enough.

Comment: But I have no idea why the sln don't work. It works flawlessly on my machine.