# VS: Make C++ project build automatically when dependant C# project is built

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, build, project

I have a solution including a C# and a C++ project. The C# depends on the C++ one, which is a library. When I make changes to the C# project and run the app, it's built automatically. But when I make changes to the C++ one and run, it's not built - I have to manually tell it to build first.

Can I make that automatic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 isn't building before a run when there are code changes. It was doing working yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646858/visual-studio-2010-isnt-building-before-a-run-when-there-are-code-changes-it-w)

Comment: @Hans: my VS is already set up as suggested in the answers there. Also  the "build before run" functionality is working, just not for the C++ project. For example, when I have a C# project dependent on another C# one, it works fine.

Comment: Same setting page, bump up the build diagnostics to 11 and dig through the trace output it generates.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click your C# project in VS.  Click "Project Dependencies".  This opens a dialog that lets you mark other projects that the target project depends on.  VS will automatically set the proper build order for when you build the whole solution.

Make sure your C++ project is set to build with the solution by right-clicking the Solution->Properties->Configuration Properties and making sure all of the projects are marked for build.

Comment: Ok, I verified both things, but they're already set up as you suggest.

Comment: As of VS2017, you need to Right-click the C# project, then look for the *Build Dependencies* menu to fine *Project Dependencies*

Comment: How about c# anycpu, and c++ build x86 and x64?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a command to build the C++ project in the CustomBuildStep property in the C# project properties. Confused? OK
Select your project on the Solution Explorer, right click it and choose "Project Properties..."
Go to the Custom Build Step category and select Command Line
In this property type:

```
make <yourprojectname
```

Hope this works!