# Main entry point not properly working when I add form with a reportviewer control

Tags: c#, winforms

I add new form ReportTest to my solution and add reportviewer control on the form. I design a new report that the reportviewer will load. I change the entry point of my program to ReportTest and run the program. The problem is when I change back the entry point to my original form and run the program it still loads the ReportTest. I tried to delete the ReportTest and the RDLC file but still it loads the ReportTest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, your application is not compiling successfully. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to Build your solution and see if any compilation error comes.

If you directly execute a solution(<kbd>F5</kbd>) in VS and the compilation fails, then VS executes the most recent successful build.

Comment: +1 for psychic debugging.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2646882/17034) for a more thorough fix.