# Clicking "Start" to install and run Excel VSTO Add-In no longer works

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, vsto

I'm not sure how my dev. environment got into this state, but if I am in Visual Studio and I press the Start button to load and run my Excel Add-In, it does not load.  What is especially puzzling is that, unlike in the past when this happens, the add-in does not appear to be disabled (in File > Options > Add-Ins), it's just not registered as an add-in at all.

However, if I find and double-click on the `.vsto` file in my `bin\Debug` folder, it installs and runs fine.  This is clearly a workaround, though, because subsequent changes to my add-in code *are not loaded* when I click "Start" again.  I need to remove the plugin (including the registry entry) and re-install by double-clicking on the `.vsto` file.

Any ideas?

Environment: Windows 7, Office 2010, Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to something similar at work (but not exactly the same)

Check the **LoadBehavior** of the add-in in registry, it should be set to 3, you can play arround with other values.

Also I remember there was a problem with the **Manifest** reg entry, it must be in some specific *uri* format, something like
file:/// | vstolocal

Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx)

In my case the addin works fine on my machine but after installing it didn't appear at end user machine

Comment: It turns out that it was a combination of problems.  First, the manifest entry was wrong (thanks for the link), and second, the project was not building when I clicked "Start".  The second issue was resolved with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646858/visual-studio-2010-isnt-building-before-a-run-when-there-are-code-changes-it-w.  Not sure how this happened; I didn't even know those settings existed.