# Visual Studio - deploys without building

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Today my VS Pro 2013 started acting up.

It stopped building my WP8 project before deploying it on the device, so I have to start the build manually and THEN start debugging. Until now I only had to tap F5 to run everything...

Is there an option connected with such behavior that might've gotten turned on/off or is it some kind of a bug in the IDE?

Comment: In the configuration manager, make sure the "Build" checkbox is checked: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC101992.jpg

Comment: Yeah, that was the first place I looked. Everything seems fine and yet VS does what it wants...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then, I found the answer:
[Visual Studio 2010 isn't building before a run when there are code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646858/visual-studio-2010-isnt-building-before-a-run-when-there-are-code-changes)

It seems that the bug isn't in the "not building before deploying" behavior itself, but in the reason why that option got changed to "Never build"...

Most likely some config file got damaged and VS reverted it to default values.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and it looks to me like a VS bug. Restarting VS helps! :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't ALWAYS help, which is annoying... :|

Comment: If restarting isn't helping it means that you still have running build process in the background. You have to kill it manually inside task manager. This situation is easy to verify if you want to delete bin folder in your solution and it is not possible because "some process" is still referencing files there.

Comment: No, I'm sure there were no processes left in the background, since I had even shut the PC down for the night ;)
Anyway, I've already found (and posted) the solution for the problem. Apparently it WAS an option after all. I don't know how it got changed though...