# C++ will change it last input

Tags: c++-cli

I don't know if anyone had the same problem.
I use Microsoft visual C++ 2010 I am new to it but I know a lot of Java program but for me trying to go from one program to another is confusing. 
Anyway I will make a basic program "Hello World" and run it it works fine but when I go and try to type something else or add something to the text it remains the same code when I run it. It does not happen all the time but it will do it a lot and it seam like it is becoming more common.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             label1 -> Text = "hello world";
         }
```

This is what I put.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             label1 -> Text = "This is a test";
         }
```

when I run the first code it works, but when I change to the code and put in the 2nd code it will remain the first code when I run it, but I change what the code say so it should change as well but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting that controls whether Visual Studio forces a build before you run, likely you set it to false.

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646858/visual-studio-2010-isnt-building-before-a-run-when-there-are-code-changes)

> Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run. "On Run, when projects are out of date" = Always build.

Comment: I cheek that out but that does not seam to be the problem.

Comment: @DoasLM: Did you try recompiling yourself? Do a rebuild to ensure your binary was updated.

Comment: I do not know how to do that Thank's

Comment: I cheek to see if that was the problem It does not seam to help so no. That did not help like I needed it to. Thank's anyway

Comment: @DoasLM: Unfortunately there is little information in your post to go off of.  You need to expand, for instance have you verified that when you build it builds successfully? Have you verified that your handler is being called in the original case? Did your builds exe creation time change? The fact is that the change you made should be reflected if everything else is okay, but the number of things that can go wrong is quite a long list so it is impossible to enumerate in this format.