# Linked files not updating

Tags: .net, vb.net

My vb.net project uses two files, 1 an Access db and the other an Excel template. I added the files as existing items, navigated to the share drive where they live and clicked ok. They are both set with Build Action=Content and Copy To Output=Always.
When I first build my project the files are copied to the local folder where the application code is. When the application is started the files are copied to the bin/debug folder.
If I update the files on the share drive the changes are never picked up, the application just continues to use the files that were copied to the application folder.  Why?  How do I fix that?

I'm using VS2013 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure but try cleaning the solution before building it by right clicking on the project in object explorer, then right click again and build it.

Or actually just right click it and select build.

You may be editing those files outside the visual studio and then just going back to it to run your solution, if that is the case, I think visual studio skips the compilation process since it doesn't see the need to do so since there are no actual changes registered by it, resulting in no files being copyed.

Maybe the accepted answer on this post can also be useful: [Visual Studio 2010 isn't building before a run when there are code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646858/visual-studio-2010-isnt-building-before-a-run-when-there-are-code-changes)