# highlight the error line in a textbox-winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to highlight the line in the text box where the error occured on parsing the JSON:

```
{
    "datalist":
    {
        "name":"abc",
        "collegename":"xyz",
        "degree":"123"
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
txtBox1.SelectionStart = txtBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(exceptionObject.Lineposition);
txtBox1.SelectionLength = 10;
txtBox1.setFocus();
```

But the text line is not highlighted when the error occurs.

Comment: Does the line position from the exception object match with the line position of the text in the textbox ?

Comment: This code cannot compile, be sure to pay attention to the Error List window after you build.  Change the settings described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2646882/17034) to ensure this cannot go wrong again.

Comment: Please provide more details for the `exceptionObject`, if this is usual Exception, then most likely it won't point to the line to provided JSON. Also the code above was just tested (with manual value of `Lineposition` and it works as expected.

Comment: Tatranskymedved-Firstly, thanks a lot.Here exceptionobject is a JsonReaderException object.